# Open and close sidebar menu on mobile not working

Tags: mobile, menu

Here's the code I'm using (here's the original code: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_overlay2)

html and js:

```
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">& times;</a>
<div class="overlay-content">
<a href="index.php">home</a>
<a href="stappenplan.php">stappenplan</a>
<a href="#overzicht">agentschappen</a>
<a href="casting-proces.php">casting proces</a>
<a href="#help">mijn hulp</a>
<a href="#contact">contact</a>
</div>
</div>

<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>

<script>
function openNav() {
document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
}
$('body').on('click', function(){
if( parseInt( $('#myNav').css('width') ) > 0 ){
closeNav();
}
});
</script>
```

For some reason, all works fine on laptop, but on mobile nothing happens when "clicking" on the three bars. Is there a js mistake here?

Also, is it possible when clicking on a menu anchor on the same page, that the menu disappears whilst scrolling to the anchor id?

Thanks for helping me out.